# Join Query for multiple fields - lucence.net search in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lucene, lucene.net

How can search on two fields like search term, city or state.  I have to do search like [justdial](http://www.justdial.com/).I am getting search results only by search term rather than term and place. I tried some code like below but I am getting exception.

## Search Method:

```
public static IEnumerable<SearchModel> Search(string input, string state, string city)
        {


            var terms = input.Trim().Replace("-", " ").Split(' ')
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => x.Trim() + "*");

               var stat = state.Trim().Replace("-", " ").Split(' ')
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => x.Trim());

         input = string.Join(" ", terms,stat);  //Joiningstate here

            return _search(input);
        }
```

## _search Method:

```
 private static IEnumerable<SearchModel> _search(string searchQuery)
        {
            // validation
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", ""))) return new List<SearchModel>();

            // set up lucene searcher
            using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false))
            {
                var hits_limit = 1000;
                var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);


                var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser
                        (Version.LUCENE_30, new[] {  "Name","StateName", "CityName" }, analyzer);
                var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);

                var hits = searcher.Search(query, null, hits_limit, Sort.INDEXORDER).ScoreDocs;
                var results = _mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);
                analyzer.Close();
                searcher.Dispose();
                return results;

            }

        }
```

## Parse Query:

```
private static Query parseQuery(string searchQuery, QueryParser parser)
        {
            Query query;
            try
            {
                query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
            }
            catch (ParseException)
            {
                query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
            }
            return query;
        }
```

But I am getting exception in Parse Query like below.
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can show us the final search string you are passing to lucene

Comment: Hi Dreamwalker, thank for your reply. I am sending input like "hotels", "cars" & "phones". And these text should be filter based on city(e.g: adak") and state(e.g: Alasaka). I am getting perfect results without city and state.

Comment: Sorry think you misunderstood run the program with the search specified and update question with the value in searchQuery from the parseQuery function

Answer (score 0):

You can try like [edial.in](http://www.edial.in/) search script. So advanced I feel